# How can create site specific virtual user for multi site implementation in Sitecore

Tags: sitecore-api, multisite, authentication, virtual-user

Currently we are creating virtual user in Sitecore (9.0.2) database once user is authenticated with backend API as shown below

```
Sitecore.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationManager.BuildVirtualUser("extranet\\" + Email, true);
```

We are checking the user is authenticated or not by using below code

```
((Sitecore.Security.Accounts.User)Sitecore.Context.User).IsAuthenticated
```

Now the problem is, we are adding one more website within same App service that will use same code. Only difference is that site1 and site2 have different virtual directory as shown below

```
Site1: www.site.come/site1
Site2: www.site.com/site2
```

We need to authenticate user against each site separately. Means one user can able to login site1 and site 2 from single browser.

Currently what is happening is that if a user logged into site 1 user is also logged into site 2. this should not happen.

Your help is most welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use separate security domains for each of the sites.

Instead of using

```
AuthenticationManager.BuildVirtualUser("extranet\\" + Email, true);
```

You should use for `site1`:

```
AuthenticationManager.BuildVirtualUser("site1\\" + Email, true);
```

and for `site2`:

```
AuthenticationManager.BuildVirtualUser("site2\\" + Email, true);
```

And then check if user is authenticated and belongs to the appropriate site domain.

Comment: thanks for the help. I have added site name in BuildVirtualUser as you said but when I am cheking user authenticated or not by domain (Sitecore.Context.User.Domain) it is NULL. can you please tell what is wrong with this

Comment: Do you have domain defined in `App_Config\Security\Domains.config`? E.g. `<domain name="site1" ensureAnonymousUser="true" />`

Comment: Thanks now it is coming after adding domain. however  facing one another issue, the custom property added to one site user is overriding on another site. virtualUser.Profile.SetCustomProperty("id", 123).
Is there any way to store custom property as domain specific user

Comment: `virtualUser.Profile.SetCustomProperty(Sitecore.Context.User.Domain+"id", 123)`

Comment: Ok Thanks Marek

Comment: when I called Sitecore.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationManager.Logout(); from site 1, it is clearing the user of Site 2. is there any logout domain based user?